# DBMS Job scheduler for materialized view

Tags: oracle, jobs, materialized-views, dbms-scheduler

I have been trying to schedule the refresh of three materialized views simultaneously every night. I have used the below code

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB 
(
JOB_NAME            => 'REFRESH_MVIEW',
JOB_TYPE            => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
JOB_ACTION          => 'BEGIN DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH("m_view1, m_view2, m_view3",''C''); END;',
NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS => 0,
START_DATE          => SYSTIMESTAMP,
REPEAT_INTERVAL     => 'FREQ=DAILY; BYHOUR=0',
END_DATE            => NULL,
ENABLED             => TRUE,
AUTO_DROP           => FALSE,
COMMENTS            => 'JOB TO REFRESH'
);
END;
```

But I am getting the following error after the job has been run

ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job 57179
ORA-06550: line ORA-06550: line 1, column 495:
PLS-00114: identifier 'm_view1, m_view2' too long
, column :

I understand that there is a constraint of 30 chars in the procedure name. So, does that mean I have to split the job into 3 different jobs? Could you please let me know where I am going wrong?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Double-quotes (`"`) are used to delimit identifiers - in your case, however, you want to pass a string literal, so you would use single-quotes (`'`). Since it's within another string, you need to escape them (`''`), but it is often easier to use the new quote syntax, e.g. `q'[BEGIN DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('m_view1, m_view2, m_view3','C'); END;]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you please let me know where I am going wrong?

Try to write your statement like that instead:

```
BEGIN DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH(''m_view1,m_view2,m_view3'',''C'')
```

Or

```
BEGIN DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH(''m_view1,m_view2,m_view3'',''CCC'')
```

View list is specified using a *string* -- so using *single quotes*. I don't know if spaces are relevant in the view list. In doubt, I've removed them too.

Please note in the first case you have a default refresh for later two views. If you need a complete refresh for all your views, you have to specify *CCC* as the *refresh method*.

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96568/rarmviea.htm#94135

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and post the results. I have used the second command with ''CCC''.